# Python type-checker can't tell we're dealing with subclasses

Tags: python, pylance, pyright

Say I have some code like this:

```py
from typing import Any


class Parent:
    def __init__(self, name: Any):
        self.name = name


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, name: Any):
        super().__init__(name)

    def print_name(self) -> None:
        print(self.name)


def create_instance(arg: Any):
    if isinstance(arg, int):
        return Parent(arg)

    return Child(arg)


def is_child_instance(obj: Any):
    return isinstance(obj, Child)


def main():
    instance_a = create_instance("a")
    instance_1 = create_instance(1)

    instances = [instance_a, instance_1]

    for instance in instances:
        if not is_child_instance(instance):
            continue

        instance.print_name()
```

By the time we get to the final line, we can be certain that we're not dealing with an instance of the Parent class, due to the `continue` statement. But the pyright language server's type-checking facility reports this: "Cannot access member print_name for type 'Parent'." We're assured to have an instance of Child, but it's still checking against Parent.

Interestingly, if I inlined the body of the `is_child_instance` function, so that the final lines looked like this:

```py
    for instance in instances:
        if not isinstance(instance, Child):
            continue

        instance.print_name()
```

Then the warning would go away... This makes me think there must be some way that I can annotate the code differently to appease the type-checker and still use an extract function to process the logic.

The details in this example are a bit contrived, but I hope it conveys the point. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You tagged the question with pylint but pylint  only raises a ``useless-parent-delegation`` line 10 for the example you gave, is this only a pyright issue ?

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas oops. I meant to put pylance, not pylint, since pylance uses pyright-language-server and reports the same error message. I will update the post. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: This is an issue of *type inference*, and yes, the most reasonable way of narrowing the type in this case is to inline your use of `isinstance`. Otherwise, you can try to use the relatively new [user-defined type guards](https://peps.python.org/pep-0647/)

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga! That link is very helpful. For anyone else reading this, the link has a section which explicitly says that the thing I want is not really available:

Comment: I should add to my last comment, not really available in Python 3.8. However on some testing it seems like you could do this in Python 3.10:


```
def is_child_instance(obj: Any) -> TypeGuard[Child]:
    return isinstance(obj, Child)
```

Comment: @NickReid it should be available in `typing_extensions` if you want it before it is in the standard library